# Simple unshift and unique not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

Very simplistic code, yet been frying my brain for a few hours? So as you can see on the `add` function, it basically takes 2 params; an IP Address & a UNIX date

```
const redis = require("redis"), client = redis.createClient();
const {promisify} = require('util');
const getAsync = promisify(client.get).bind(client);
const setAsync = promisify(client.set).bind(client);

_ = require('lodash');
_weg = require('wegweg')({
    globals: false
});

module.exports = {

    add: async function (ip, cday) {
        var key = _weg.md5('dact:' + ip);
        return await getAsync(key).then((result) => {
            let value;
            if (result == null) {
                value = [];
            } else {
                value = result;
            }
            value = value.unshift(cday);
            value = _.uniq(value);
            return setAsync(key, value);
        });
    }

};
```

So if I'm going ahead and passing both:

```
await ping_history.add("127.0.0.1", 1562774400);
```

It seems to not be inserting an array or something? `key` should be an **MD5** & `value` should simply be an array of dates which are all unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unshift` method modifies the array in place, it doesn't return a new array. The return value of `unshift` is the new length of the array. So after

```
value = value.unshift(cday);
```

the `value` variable now contains a number, not the array.

```js
value = [1, 2, 3, 4];
value = value.unshift(10);
console.log(value);
```

Just write

```
value.unshift(cday);
```

without reassigning the variable.